# How to efficiently retrieve all the inner elements/ndarray from a nested ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```py
np_array_a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,0]]) # can have any number of rows but 2 columns
np_array_b = np.array([[5,6], [7,8], [5,0]]) # can have any number of rows but 2 columns
dct={"a": np_array_a, "b": np_array_b}
```

I want to extract the inner numpy elements from the `dct` and make a new numpy array. For example, for python list I can use `*` operator to extract elements. I know I can iterate through the `dct` and achieve it but was wondering if there is any **numpy** way of doing it?

New numpy array should be of the following form:

```
new_np_array = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,0],[5,6], [7,8], [5,0]])
```

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? There must be more context here.

Comment: what do you mean by 'extract' you can slice your array like so: a[0] and a[1]

Comment: maybe `a, b = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])`?

Comment: The important question that needs to be answered, is what operations you are trying to do with the sub elements? Perhaps a better way is to [edit] your question to show what is the expected result.

Comment: `numpy` does not have a way of doing things with dictionaries.  You have to use the ordinary dictionary index or iteration, `dct['a']` etc.

Comment: `np.vstack((np_array_a, np_array_b))` will make a new array from the 2 originals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing:

```
a[0]
#[1,2]
```

and

```
a[1]
#[3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use list comprehension:

```
extract = [item for nested_list in np_array for item in nested_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_array = np.concatenate(list(dct.values()))
```

Result:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 0],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8],
       [5, 0]])
```

Comment: dct.values() does not guarantee the order.

Comment: On python 3.7+ it does.  In any case, this could have easily been `np.concatenante((np_array_a, np_array_b))` but it's not clear why OP wanted it in a `dict` first.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `vstack`:

```
np.vstack([np_array_a,np_array_b])
```